# Finding the farthest point from a set of other points

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, graph-colorings, graph-distance

I have a set of nodes in a very large graph which I call Cluster Points. I also have for each point in the graph, the distance from each point in the Cluster point set.

For example: `node_id: 2493` is 5 hops (distance) away from the first cluster point, 2 hops from the second and 8 hops from the third.

What I would like to do is to find points which far away from the whole set. Such a point would further be added to the Cluster Point set. In essence, I am trying to distribute these cluster points evenly throughout the graph.

However, given these distances I have no idea on how to find a point far away from the current set of cluster points. Any thoughts or ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of choosing a sequence of nodes in a graph in which each is approximately as far as possible from the previously chosen ones was considered in my preprint with Har-Peled and Sidiropoulos, [arXiv:1507.01555](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01555). We provided a randomized $(1+\epsilon)$-approximation (that is, each point is within that factor of farthest) running in expected time $O(\epsilon^{-1}(m+n)\log n\log(n/\epsilon))$, within logarithmic factors of linear.